# change hover to click on function in Themify - Product Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the "Themify - WooCommerce Product Filter"-Plugin in WP and trying to change the hover effect of the filter items from hover to on click, so that the filter options of each filter don't show by mouseover, but by clicking on it.

The html code structure produced for every filter by the plug-in looks like this:

```
<div class="wpf_item wpf_item_pa_options">
    <label class="wpf_item_name" for="wpf_wpf_60c3c74370f1a_item_pa_options">Options</label>
    <div class="wpf_items_group">
        <ul class="wpf_column_horizontal">
            <li class="wpf_pa_options_215">
                <input   id="wpf_wpf_60c3c74370f1a_215" type="checkbox" name="wpf_pa_options[]" value="option_1" />
                 <label for="wpf_wpf_60c3c74370f1a_215">Option_1</label>
            </li>
            <li class="wpf_pa_options_85">
                <input   id="wpf_wpf_60c3c74370f1a_85" type="checkbox" name="wpf_pa_options[]" value="option_2" />
                <label for="wpf_wpf_60c3c74370f1a_85">Option_2</label>
            </li>
        </ul>                                                                   
    </div>                            
</div>
```

I tried to solve it by preventing the hover effect in css:

```
.wpf_item.et-touch-hover>.wpf_items_group,
.wpf_item:hover>.wpf_items_group {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.wpf_item.et-touch-hover>.wpf_items_group,
.wpf_item:not( :hover )>.wpf_items_group {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.show-filter {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
    display: block !important;
}
```

And adding a click function with jQuery:

```
$(".wpf_item_pa_options").click(function(){  
    $(".wpf_item_pa_options > .wpf_items_group").toggleClass("show-filter");  
    $(".wpf_item_pa_other > .wpf_items_group").removeClass("show-filter");  
});  
$(".wpf_item_pa_other").click(function(){  
    $(".wpf_item_pa_other > .wpf_items_group").toggleClass("show-filter");  
    $(".wpf_item_pa_options > .wpf_items_group").removeClass("show-filter");  
});
```

The hover effect don't show anymore, but the click on function does not work.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try changing to `.on('click',function()`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work